# Please recommend a graphics card for GPU programming

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I'm looking for a recommendation for a graphics card for use in experimenting with GPU programming.  I'm leaning more towards OpenCL over CUDA.  Also looking for a card that's reasonably priced (is anything available for $50 or less?)

Comment: Anything that runs CUDA runs OpenCL. Hardware recommendations are questions where any answers will be obsolete tomorrow seem to be frowned upon. (Chat might be more appropriate place for this, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html suggests so). An 8400 GS can be picked up pretty cheap and I think these will run CUDA/OpenCL.

Comment: Note that AMD propose an OpenCL driver that runs on CPU. Depending on your needs, it may help you to learn/prototype.

Comment: @awoodland, it doesn't have to be the "latest & greatest" in fact I'm hoping to pick up something used so I doubt it will be "obsolete tomorrow".

Comment: Eventually, which one did you have pick ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All NVIDIA graphics cards in [this list](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html) support both CUDA and OpenCL. All ATI graphics cards in [this list](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/ATIStreamSDK/Pages/default.aspx#two) support OpenCL. Some are under $50.